# using if else with eval in aspx page

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

Is there a way to use an else if on the following eval on the aspx page .

Currently my div is as follows :

```
  <div class="tooltip" style="display: none">                                                                  
        <div style="text-align: center; font-weight: normal">
                Value = <%# Eval("Percentage") + "%" %>     
        </div>
  </div>
```

I would like to use the following logic on my div :

```
If(Percentage < 50)
   display "0 %"
   else 
   display "percentage"
```

I tried something like this but it doesn't work :

```
if (<%# Eval("Percentage") %> < 50)
{
    Eval("0");
}
else
{
   <%# Eval("PassPercentage") + "%" %> 
 }
```

I want to know if such an operation is possible  to do on the aspx page. I cannot do it in aspx.cs.

Comment: Why is it not possible to use code-behind class for this?

Comment: I am using the div to display in jquery tool tip . I would like to do it on the aspx page . If its possible.

Comment: You could use a ternary operator

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ASP.NET using Bind/Eval in .aspx in If statement](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5596484/asp-net-using-bind-eval-in-aspx-in-if-statement)

Comment: Check this: https://www.codingfusion.com/Post/If-Else-statement-in-webforms-aspx-page

Answer (score 64, accepted):

If you absolutely do not want to use code-behind, you can try conditional operator for this:

```
<%# ((int)Eval("Percentage") < 50) ? "0 %" : Eval("Percentage") %>
```

That is assuming field `Percentage` contains integer.

Update: Version for VB.NET, just in case, provided by [tomasofen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1253788/tomasofen):

```
<%# If(Eval("Status") < 50, "0 %", Eval("Percentage")) %>
```

Comment: The user was asking for C#, but i arrive here from search engine looking for VB.NET version, so i suppose this can help "another me" in the future: 

<%# If(Eval("Status") < 50, "0 %", Eval("Percentage")) %>

Enjoy it

Answer (score 19):

You can try 
 c#

```
public string ProcessMyDataItem(object myValue)
 {
  if (myValue == null)
   {
   return "0 %"";
  }
   else
  {
     if(Convert.ToInt32(myValue) < 50)
       return "0";
     else
      return myValue.ToString() + "%";
  }

 }
```

asp

```
 <div class="tooltip" style="display: none">                                                                  
      <div style="text-align: center; font-weight: normal">
   Value =<%# ProcessMyDataItem(Eval("Percentage")) %> </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: +1 Thanks ! This is a working solution too . but I am looking for something do do on the aspx page itself.

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to bind is a Model class, you can add a new readonly property to it like:

```
public string FormattedPercentage
{
    get
    {
        If(this.Percentage < 50)
            return "0 %";
        else 
            return string.Format("{0} %", this.Percentage)        
     }
}
```

Otherwise you can use Andrei's or kostas ch. suggestions if you cannot modify the class itself

Comment: Thanks ! This is helpful. but I am not using Percentage as a property. But it would be something that would be useful in the future.

Answer (score 1):

```
<%# (string)Eval("gender") =="M" ? "Male" :"Female"%>
```

Comment: Generally avoid code-only answers.  Consider adding a `description` or at least show more context that helps to explain your code.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
 <%if (System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["OperationalMode"] != "live") {%>
                        &nbsp;[<%=System.Environment.MachineName%>]
                        <%}%>
```