# Eval function for checkbox

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, webforms

This is my html code inside the gridview.. I want to add "**OR**" condition in Eval function..

how can i do?

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Report" HeaderStyle-CssClass="headerfont">
       <ItemTemplate>
          <asp:CheckBox ID="checkReport" runat="server" Checked='<%# bool.Parse(Eval("rm_rights").ToString() == "1R" ? "True": "False") %>'
             Enabled="true" AutoPostBack="True"  /> 
          </ItemTemplate>
          <HeaderStyle CssClass="headerfont"></HeaderStyle>
             <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
           </asp:TemplateField>
```

i need code like this

```
`Checked='<%# bool.Parse(Eval("rm_rights").ToString() == "2R" ? "True": "False") %>'`
```

OR  operator

```
Checked='<%# bool.Parse(Eval("rm_rights").ToString() == "3R" ? "True": "False") %>'
```

Comment: Could you be more specific?

Comment: Well it'd be `||`, no?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17067219/using-if-else-with-eval-in-aspx-page

Comment: Check this link
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17067219/using-if-else-with-eval-in-aspx-page

Answer (score 0):

you are using bool function and u evaluate this expression with 1R so it gives u error .
remove bool.parse function and check again

Answer (score 0):

Try this , You have misplaced the bracket ,<%# ... %> block supports conditional operator, eval is a different function
" <%# Eval("rm_rights").ToString() == "1R" ? "True": "False" %>"