# asp.net c# using if conditions with Bind

Tags: c#, asp.net, if-statement, bind

with asp.net c# I get the code of a country with bind :

```
<asp:Label runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("h_country") %>' ID="Label1"></asp:Label>
```

this return code of country like usa, tr, eg, il.

I need to put if conditions and I try to do it like this:

```
<asp:Label runat="server" Text='<%# if(Bind("h_country")=="usa") resonse.write("United States"); %>' ID="Label1"></asp:Label>
```

note: I'm using GridView and template.
I tried alo at code behind to get the value of country like this:

```
String s = Lable1.Text;
```

but also not workes! 
how can I get it as a variable and use if condition ?

Comment: This will be painful for you as you go forward. I would recommend doing the conversion in code behind. Also, don't hardcode countries, put them in a database and pull the 'Text' instead of the 'Code' when binding. I.E. instead of binding 'USA', send 'United States' from the beginning.

Comment: mmmm, I thought doing this, but I wondered if there is any way to put if statement here

Comment: Take a look at this question and answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5596484/asp-net-using-bind-eval-in-aspx-in-if-statement. The `Label` control has got `DataBinding` event that You could probably use to handle the logic in the code-behind: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.databinding%28v=vs.110%29.aspx.

Comment: I just answer pretty much the identical question:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24568774/how-to-use-if-else-statement-in-databinder-eval-in-asp-net/24576888#24576888

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can do conditional checks in the markup while binding. Try something like below but I would not advise doing this kind of conditional checks and response.write at the template level but do it in code behind.

```
<asp:Label runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("h_country") == "usa" ? "United States" : (string)Bind("h_country") %>' ID="Label1"></asp:Label>
```

And this is how you can do it at code behind. Use the `databound` event to find the `Label1` and set the appropriate text in there.

You need to define `OnRowDataBound="gvTest_DataBound` for the gridview in the markup

```
protected void gvTest_DataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
  {
     Label lblCountry = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("Label1");
     if (lblCountry.text == "usa"){
      // do something here
     }
     else {
      // do something otherwise
     }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use find control if thus label is within the gridview and then get the sting from label.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to handle this in the code behind

```
<asp:Label runat="server" Text='<%# GetCountry(Eval("h_country")) %>' ID="Label1"></asp:Label>
```

code behind

```
    public string GetCountry(object country)
    {
        if (county.ToString() == "usa")
        return "United States";
    }
```

It would be better if you had a lookup so you don't have to have a lot of if statements